# How to optimaly merge two arrays of different objects based on an attribute?

Tags: typescript, performance, merge, overwrite, code-cleanup

First question here (I mean like ever), so sorry if I posted at the wrong section or haven't found an already given answer.
I have 2 arrays of objects. The first one, lets call it oldArray has 1000 objects with attributes
{id, name, age, address, favourite number, favourite mathematician}.

The other one, lets call it inputArray has 20 objects which attributes are a subset of the objects in oldArray, for example
{id, age, favourite number}.

What I need is to create an updatedArray, lets call it newArray in which the objects from the oldArray which IDs aren't in the inputArray stay unaltered, but the attributes of the objects which IDs exist in the inputArray are overwritten by the new ones.

I have made it work with fors and ifs but I am searching for
a) a more efficent way
b) a "cleaner" way, like using lodash or something I don't know :P
c) preferably both of the above

So expected results.

let oldArray=[
{
id:1,
name:Akis,
age: 27,
address: Mykonos,
favourite number: 23,
favourite mathematician: Riemann
},
{
id: 2,
name: Mary,
age: 41,
address: Paros,
favourite number: 10,
favourite mathematician: Ramanujan
},
{
id: 3,
name: Sofia,
age: 13,
address: Ithaka,
favourite number: 4,
favourite mathematician: Gauss
},
{
id:4,
name: Anthony,
age: 18,
address: Koufonisia,
favourite number: 33,
favourite mathematician: Metallica
},
{
id:5,
name:Yolo,
age: 99,
address: Somewhere,
favourite number: 123,
favourite mathematician: Euler
}
]

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let inputArray = [
{
id: 2,
age: 23,
favourite number: 13
},
{
id:5,
age: 100,
favourite number: 99
}
]

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

let newArray = [
{
id:1,
name:Akis,
age: 27,
address: Mykonos,
favourite number: 23,
favourite mathematician: Riemann
},
{
id: 2,
name: Mary,
age: 23,_________________________________// !CHANGED!
address: Paros,
favourite number: 13,____________________// !CHANGED!
favourite mathematician: Ramanujan
},
{
id: 3,
name: Sofia,
age: 13,
address: Ithaka,
favourite number: 4,
favourite mathematician: Gauss
},
{
id:4,
name: Anthony,
age: 18,
address: Koufonisia,
favourite number: 33,
favourite mathematician: Metallica
},
{
id:5,
name:Yolo,
age: 100,_________________________________// !CHANGED!
address: Somewhere,
favourite number: 99,_____________________// !CHANGED!
favourite mathematician: Euler
}
]

PS. I am missing some quotes but i Hope you get the point! :P

Comment: Since you only mention your current solution as "fors and ifs" without showing us (as in a [mcve]) it's hard to tell you what to change.  Is `newArray` supposed to contain completely distinct objects from `oldArray` (i.e., copies of them)?  I'd probably save the new array as an object `n` keyed by `id`, and then do an `oldArray.map(i => Object.assign({}, i, n[i.id]))`

Comment: Also, "I am missing some quotes" means "my code will not compile" and therefore "you will have to rewrite the code to be valid if you want to test your solution".  Please check the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes [good example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Good luck!